# TensorFlow native, tf.keras, and Eager Execution execution time

Tags: performance, tensorflow

I'm trying to compare the running time of the same model implemented in native tensorflow, eager execution and with tf.keras. The model is for a question answering task, and I've tested two alternatives - by providing only the sentence which contains the answer, and providing the whole context.

The results for training over 200 epochs are rather strange and I don't know how to interpret them.

1. Case of keeping all sentences:

   - tf : 704.18 secs
   - tf.keras: 1235.81 secs
   - eager: 17057.66 secs
2. Case of one sentence:

   - tf : 94.56 secs
   - tf.keras: 36.48 secs
   - eager: 252.08 secs

Generally one could say from the numbers, that TF pure is faster than tf.keras when the dataset size increases, but tf.keras was faster for the small data input. But why is this the case? And I can't explain why eager so slow is... I know it does not construct flow graphs in the background and therefore no optimizations are happening explicitly, but the difference is too big.

You can find my implementations in here: https://github.com/simonada/q-and-a-tensorflow. I would be really interested to discuss whether this benchmarking makes sense, and how to make it more consistent.

Comment: It's interesting that eager is so slow. Did you try profiling it with python's profiler?

Comment: it is possible that in eager youre copying the data from CPU to GPU for each iteration. can you confirm that you are not doing this ?

Comment: Hi @harveyslash, I was not using GPU for the tasks. I converted my data to TFRecords and was iterating over the data with tfe.Iterator.